# going to (become): which form in past?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-choice

When talking to someone, and he doesn't listen to you, even though you repeat it, do you ask him:

"Do you went deaf?" or "Did you go deaf?" or "Do you became deaf?"

Comment: Your title seems to ask a different question than the body of your question. Is this correct? Could you make them relate?

Comment: _Do you went_ and _do you became_ are not valid  verb forms. It's the auxiliary verb _do_ which needs to be in the past tense - _did you go_ or _did you become_. What I would probably say in those circumstances is "Have you gone deaf?"

Comment: If someone isn't listening, you might ask, "Are you deaf?" but it would be very rude. If you actually suspect that a person can't hear you, it is polite to ask, "I'm sorry, can you hear me?" or, "I'm sorry, do I need to speak up?" If you are in a meeting at work and someone isn't listening, you should say politely, "please pay attention, you need to hear this," or something like that.